# NIFI Workflow Failure Entry

Tags: apache-nifi

I have got few processors like Select Hive and Put HDFS and I need a contemporary way to insert a Hive Query into a table when any of the processor fails in the workflow.

P.S I tried connecting all the failure entries via funnel but any better thought will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good way to use funnel. I would recommend you to make a different process group for handling errors. Mainly for a better monitoring later and flow lisibility, like this :

[image]

You can also use input and output port that give you a good visibility and you can handle each errors differently.

for exemple :

make outpout port in your main flow :

[image]

handle each error in a different process group, with input port :

[image]

then rely both :

[image]